# Нужна ли запятая, закрывающая придаточную, в конце перечисления или достаточно тире?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

Придя в лес, я услышала, как поют разные птицы: соловьи, жаворонки, синицы, - как дятел пускает барабанную дробь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Тире** в этом предложении ставить **не нужно**, так как однородные члены завершают первое предложение, а не находятся в середине. Далее ставим запятую, чтобы разделить однородные придаточные .

Comment: Я процитировал Вас в своем ответе.

Comment: Конечно, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 2):

По правилам тире требуется в конце перечисения, а запятая разделяет однородные придаточные. Розенталь не дает однозначного ответа. Он пишет, что запятая ставится, а тире или ставится, или опускается.

> [§ 15. Обобщающие слова при однородных членах предложения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=76)
>   Если по условиям контекста после однородных членов предложения требуется постановка запятой, то она ставится, а тире или ставится, или опускается. Ср.: Наряду с иными стихийными бедствиями, как-то: пожар, град, начисто выбивающий хлебные поля, ненастье или, наоборот, великая сушь, — есть в деревне ещё одно бедствие (Сол.) — запятая закрывает обособленный оборот с предложным сочетанием наряду с; Владелец тщательно осведомляется о ценах на разные большие произведения, как-то: муку, пеньку, мёд и прочее, но покупает только небольшие безделушки (Г.) — запятая как бы «поглощает» тире.

Я бы, пожалуй, обошелся запятой (просто потому, что отсутствие тире не мешает правильному пониманию текста).

**Придя в лес, я услышала, как поют разные птицы: соловьи, жаворонки, синицы,  как дятел пускает барабанную дробь.**

Дополнение.

Появился ответ Екатерины Каштановой (см. ниже), который все ставит на свои места: тире в этом предложении не просто нежелательно, ставить его **не нужно**, так как однородные члены завершают первое предложение, а не находятся в середине.

Answer (score 1):

Есть основания поставить в этом месте **точку с запятой**:

**Придя в лес, я услышала, как поют разные птицы: соловьи, жаворонки, синицы; как дятел пускает барабанную дробь.**

> Точка с запятой
>
> § 133. *Точка с запятой ставится между значительно распространенными придаточными предложениями, подчиненными одному и тому же главному, если между придаточными нет сочинительного союза, особенно когда внутри таких придаточных имеются в свою очередь придаточные предложения*, например:
>
> Не потерплю, чтоб развратитель огнем и вздохов, и похвал младое сердце
>   искушал; чтоб червь презренный, ядовитый точил лилеи стебелек; чтобы
>   двухутренний цветок увял еще полураскрытый.  Пушкин
>
> *(ПРАВИЛА РУССКОЙ ОРФОГРАФИИ И ПУНКТУАЦИИ /1956/; Из предисловия к*
>   *первому изданию: "При окончательной подготовке свода этих правил были*
>   *привлечены к работе... и заместитель главного редактора журнала*
>   *«Русский язык в школе» кандидат филологических наук Д. Э. Розенталь."*)

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/143-tz

Comment: Я не против постановки точки с запятой, но формально придаточные предложения не являются членами главного предложения, то есть Вы действуете не строго по правилу, а по аналогии.

Comment: Вы правы, больше подходит другое правило, из следующего параграфа (заменил), сам же я действовал по интуиции, потом нашлись и правила под это :)

Answer (score 0):

Соглашаясь с М_Г, я бы тоже обошлась запятой «потому, что отсутствие тире не мешает правильному пониманию текста». Более того, присутствие тире, на мой взгляд, будет мешать правильному пониманию текста.